# Python IDLE not working (ZeroDivisionError)

Tags: python, python-idle

When attempting to open IDLE, nothing happens, and when I try running IDLE in a command prompt, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw", line 17, in <module>
    idlelib.pyshell.main()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\pyshell.py", line 1516, in main
    shell = flist.open_shell()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\pyshell.py", line 329, in open_shell
    self.pyshell = PyShell(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\pyshell.py", line 874, in __init__
    OutputWindow.__init__(self, flist, None, None)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\outwin.py", line 80, in __init__
    EditorWindow.__init__(self, *args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\editor.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.set_width()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\editor.py", line 366, in set_width
    self.width = pixel_width // zero_char_width
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I can't seem to find a different post about this specific error. How do I fix this

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue lied in my `.idlerc` folder. I use custom themes and after deleting that folder entirely, IDLE functions properly.

If anyone is curious and has this same problem I have, the full path of `.idlerc` is in `C:\Users\(user)\.idlerc\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the python and idle. Although the error means that in line

> self.width = pixel_width // zero_char_width

zero_char_width=0 and any number divide by 0 gives the error

> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if `pixel_width` is zero and the problem is a *ZeroDivisionError*:

```
Try:
    self.width = pixel_width // zero_char_width
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(e)
```

This is a hint for debugging and most likely won't cure your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this error before.  Here is the relevant code from idlelib/editor.py.

```
    # Divide the width of the Text widget by the font width,
    # which is taken to be the width of '0' (zero).
    # http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M21
    zero_char_width = \
        Font(text, font=text.cget('font')).measure('0')
    self.width = pixel_width // zero_char_width
```

You must have selected a non-default font which gave a 0 measure for '0'.  Now that you deleted .idlerc, do you remember what font that was?  (Your custom color theme should not have affected this.)  I'd like to know if this is a one-off glitch or if this code needs a patch.

Whoever wrote that line obviously assumed that a 0 width for '0' was impossible.  Unless a font maps codepoint 48 (ord('0')) to nothing or a zero-width 'character', which would be very strange, width 0 would be a bug in font data, tk, or Windows.